# How to hide element in internet explorer without jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I would like to hide an image on my site using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   $('body').find('img[src$="myimage.png"]').remove(); });
```

Is there any way to convert this to javascript and still make it work in internet explorer??

Comment: `.style.display = "none"`?

Comment: Yeah, but "display: none, visibility: hidden, and opacity: 0" don't work in Internet Explorer

Comment: All three of those work in Internet Explorer. And so does jQuery, for that matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume you mean convert to vanilla js (without needing jquery lib).. this should work

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    const els = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
    for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
        let src = els[i].getAttribute("src");
        if (src == "myimage.png") {
            els[i].style.display = "none";
            break;
        }
    }
});
```